# Loop until a specific element is found on the webpage

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Hi Im using selenium to loop through a webpage after a specified element. The problem is that the element only appears on specific time. And i dont know when.

So the problem I am having is to refresh the page every 5 second to see if the element has appeared.

```
      while( !done){
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            if( driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("The Element im looking for")).isDisplayed()){
            driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("The Element im looking for")).click();
            done=true;
            }
        }
```

I asking if its possible to refresh the page every 5 second to look after the specific element. To run a loop over and refresh the page.

Comment: what is your problem here?

Comment: 1. You are not asking anything. 2. Usually, if some web elements are loaded into the client page gradually, then refreshing the page simply starts over the loading process (and does not accelerate it, as you seem to be expecting).

Comment: The thing Im wondering is if its possible to write the the program so it refresh the page every 5 second. As it is for now it goes through the page and dont update it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Thread.sleep()`

```
while( !done){
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            if( driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("The Element im looking for")).isDisplayed()){
            driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("The Element im looking for")).click();
            done=true;
            }else
              Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
```